# Surface integral Vs Volume Integral

Tags: homework-and-exercises, continuum-mechanics

Can I rewrite the continuity equation like this ? :
$$
\iiint\limits_{V}\dfrac{\partial\rho}{\partial t}\mathrm dV +\iiint\limits_{V}\rho\boldsymbol{\nabla\cdot}\mathbf v\,\mathrm dV + \iiint\limits_{V}\mathbf v\boldsymbol{\cdot\nabla}\rho\,\mathrm dV=0
\tag{01}\label{01}
$$

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), as was requested in Step 1 of the instructions when asking a question.

Comment: Please clarify the full context of your problem for other users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from the continuity equation $$\frac{\partial \rho(t, \mathbf{x})}{\partial t} +\mathbf{\nabla} \cdot \mathbf{j}(t, \mathbf{x})=0 \tag{1} \label{1}$$ with $$\mathbf{j}(t, \mathbf{x})=\rho(t, \mathbf{x})\, \mathbf{v}(t, \mathbf{x}), \tag{2} \label{2}$$ you find $$\frac{\partial \rho(t,\mathbf{x})}{\partial t}+\rho(t,\mathbf{x})\,\mathbf{\nabla}\cdot \mathbf{v}(t,\mathbf{x})+\mathbf{v}(t, \mathbf{x})\cdot\mathbf{\nabla} \rho(t, \mathbf{x})=0. \tag{3} \label{3}$$ Integrating \eqref{3} over an arbitrary three-dimensional domain $V \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ obviously yields $$\int\limits_V \! d^3x \left( \frac{\partial \rho(t,\mathbf{x})}{\partial t}+ \rho(t,\mathbf{x}) \,\mathbf{\nabla}\cdot \mathbf{v}(t, \mathbf{x})+ \mathbf{v} \cdot \mathbf{\nabla} \rho(t,\mathbf{x})    \right)=0. \tag{4} \label{4}$$ Conversely, if \eqref{4} holds for arbitrary $V \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ (subject to some mathematical qualification), the local version \eqref{3} is implied.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, it is "legal" to do this. You can compare your expression with the continuity equation in differential form

$$\frac{\partial\rho}{\partial t}+\nabla\cdot\mathbf{j}=0$$